# touchesBegan not being called

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I'm using a UIPicker to populate a UITextField instead of a keyboard. This works great but I can't close the UIPicker now. I want to be able to tap anywhere on the screen and close the UIPicker. I've tried each of the touches method an none will fire.

setUserInteractionEnabled:YES.
Not sure if it makes a difference but I'm using a StoryBoard

Should I have set something up in my AppDelegate to listen for touches?

Here is my .h

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface RNMemberTableViewController : UITableViewController<UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate, UITextFieldDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIPickerView *behaviorPicker;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIDatePicker *dateOfRecordPicker;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *behaviorLevels;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *behaviorTextField;

@end
```

here is some of the implementation...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.view setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [self buildBehaviorPicker];
    NSLog(@"Member View");
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    NSLog(@"test");
    [self.view touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    int tCount = touch.tapCount;
    NSLog(@"Touched %d", tCount);
}

- (void) buildBehaviorPicker
{
    behaviorLevels = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"Unsatisfactory", @"Needs Improvement", @"Satisfactory", @"Outstanding", nil];

    UIPickerView *pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc] init];
    pickerView.dataSource = self;
    pickerView.delegate = self;
    [pickerView selectRow:2 inComponent:0 animated:NO];
    self.behaviorTextField.inputView = pickerView;


}
```

Thanks in advance
-Bob

Comment: Bob, if you liked the working answer mark it as "answered" accordingly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can always try the following:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapReceived:)];
    [tapGestureRecognizer setDelegate:self];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tapGestureRecognizer];
}

-(void)tapReceived:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapGestureRecognizer
{
    // do something, like dismiss your view controller, picker, etc., etc.
}
```

Hope this helps ...

Comment: This worked great but any idea why touchesBegan won't fire? Is this best practice? I'm very new to Obj-C

Comment: I'd still like to know why the touches method aren't firing

Comment: If you set this up on a regular (non-table view controller) you'll see different results using touchesBegan() - the table is catching.  But, the right way to do this is still using a gesture recognizer.

Comment: To make this code work, you need your view controller to conform to this delegate too: <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>

Comment: @Alan_s Not needed at all.

Comment: Yes, This seems to be the correct way to implement this scenario, rather than using `UIResponder`

Answer (score -1):

You can add a transparent button of the same size as the controller's view under the picker.

Set `button.hidden = NO` when the picker is shown and set `button.hidden = YES` when the picker is hidden.

There are ways to hide the picker. The easiest way is to set `picker.hidden = YES`.

Answer (score -5):

If you are using UIScrollView then

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
```

will not be called, as touchesBegan is a method of UIView and not of UIScrollView.

Comment: Actually touchesBegan is a method of UIResponder.  UIView inherits from UIResponder and UIScrollView inherits from UIView, so the reasoning here can't be accurate.